# Swagger not defining parameters properly

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using .netcore to create a simple REST API and have used the swashbuckle package (swashbuckle.aspnetcore\1.1.0) so that I can devtest it easily.

**ConfigureServices:**

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Title = "Meetings Calculator API",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "An API to provide pricing information related to journeys",
            });
        });
```

**Configure**

```
app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API v1");
        });
```

All is well except for a post call I have developed. It appears that the dictionary I have defined to be passed in the body is not served over to the service correctly.

**Method Signature**

```
[HttpPost("CalculateCost", Name = "CalculateCost")]
public IActionResult getJourneyCalculation([FromBody] IDictionary<String, String> locations)
```

**Generated json config**

```
"parameters":[  
     {  
        "name":"locations",
        "in":"body",
        "required":false,
        "schema":{  
           "type":"object",
           "additionalProperties":{  
              "type":"string"
           }
        }
     }
  ],
```

I think that is the point where the dictionary is supposed to be so I think the config side of this is not working correctly. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to pick up the IDictionary correctly?

I came across a post that discussed this which stated that there was a bug (or at least inconsitency) with the spelling causing problems "s" v "S" in String but I have tried both with no change. I think this was also old and quoted as fixed. I also tried a few suggestions altering the UseSwaggerUI endpoint but all that did for me was to leave me with a blank screen.

[UPDATE]
I seem to be getting just one entry from the dictionary so for instance if I use the intput:

```
{
    "2":"London",
    "2":"Bristol",
    "2":"London",
    "2":"Newcastle"
}
```

the last entry will make it to the controller.

[UPDATE]
I have tried it with  and it will work intermittently:

```
 with arguments ([""]) - ModelState is Invalid

 with arguments (["System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]"]) - ModelState is Valid
```

with the same inputs:

```
{
    "London":2,
    "Bristol:2",
    "London:2",
    "Newcastle":2
}
```

Intermittent is a bit of a claim as it worked twice and not since.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found my way around this by defining my own class to hold the two values instead.

```
public class FromLocation
{
    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Attendees { get; set; }
}
```

Changed the controllers signature to:

```
 public IActionResult getJourneyCalculation([FromBody] IList<FromLocation> locations)
```

now the yellow schema box lists the type and I can send the information over as required. Not sure what was going on with the dictionary but life is too short.